# Connecting boolean method from another class to main

Tags: java, object, methods, boolean

Beginner to Java here. I've been researching how to do this, but I guess I'm researching the wrong thing..
My program inputs numbers and calculates what the user inputted. I figured out how to connect a different class (the one that calculates everything) to the main class (the one that will just output everything).
What I'm finding difficulty on is how to connect a boolean, not a void, method to the main class.

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //forgot to add scanner
        ExampleClass ex = new ExampleClass();
        System.out.println("Enter numbers  <enter -1 to stop>");

        number = in.nextInt(); //user inputs a number

        boolean inputData = true; //researched about this, but it doesn't work

        ex.inputData(); //doesn't work either
    }
}
```

second class:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    int numberOfThings = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    public ExampleClass()
    {
        // constructor
    }

    public boolean inputData(int number)
    {
        if(number >= 0)
        {
            numberOfThings++; 
        }
        else if (number <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Out of range");
            return false;
        }

        return true;      
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure my if statement needs work, my only question is how do I connect the boolean method to my main class (Driver)? I'm trying to piece together how to connect methods and such before I start my real project.

```
boolean inputData = true; 
ex.inputData();
```

does not work.

I just provided an example, my coding isn't complete yet.

update: this worked, posting this in case anyone searching needs this.

```
boolean inputData = true;

while (inputData) 
{ 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
number = in.nextInt();
inputData = ex.inputData(in.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly loop until the input is false? I don't really know what you want:

```
System.out.println("Enter numbers  <enter -1 to stop>");

ExampleClass ex = new ExampleClass();
boolean inputData = true;

while (inputData) { // loop until it's false to keep gaining numbers
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // to get input
    inputData = ex.inputData(input.nextInt()); // equals the return of inputData
}
```

Comment: My question is how do you connect a boolean method from a different class to the main. I just provided an example code I'm testing to provide a visual example of what I need help on.

Comment: @user3315017 well my answered covered that as well.

Comment: Yes I see that, but you don't have to answer the loop part is all I'm saying. I tried the last line of code and it doesn't work, are you saying I should tweak it a bit? I also did (inputdata.nextInt()) to check if it was just a typo.

Comment: @user3315017 How does it "not work"? I have no idea how to test this or answer it in a better way because I have no information on your actual code. You pass it a number, assign the return value to a boolean. I'm not sure what's not working.

Comment: @user3315017 There is no typo. `input` is the `Scanner`. Show us your actual code.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't realize you renamed the scanner to "input." This was mine `inputData = ex.inputData(in.nextInt());` and the error is "required: int, int and found: int."

Comment: @user3315017 Does the inputData method have two parameters?

Comment: Wow I said int grade twice in the boolean method. Works now.

Answer (score 2):

You nearly have it, instead of:

```
    boolean inputData = true;

    ex.inputData();
```

do

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean inputData = ex.inputData(in.nextInt());
```

Comment: inputData takes in a int.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I'm working on the code in NetBeans and it says that I need to make a method in driver.ExampleClass. I thought that this is a method already?

Comment: That's because your inputData method was expecting an integer to be passed in. I added some example code that reads a number the user types when they run the program.

Comment: You probably want to do a loop around the whole input process as well, I'll leave that for you to work out though.